# Calculate phase shift between two signals

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals, noise, phase

Consider the measurements of two modulated AC signals (voltage and current) which may have noise, harmonics and a DC bias. Each measured signal consists of a list for the time and a list for the corresponding values.

My goal is to find out the phase shift in degrees between these two signals in a robust way.

I would like to realize this in the frequency domain perhaps by calculating and evaluating the fundamental waves of the signals.

Any help or sample code (MATLAB) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: By "phase shift" do you really mean "time shift"?

Comment: I mean the phase shifting between current and voltage. E.g.: In the case of a capacitor, the current leads the voltage by 90 degrees. I want to calculate that 90 degrees.

Comment: correct. filtering does nothing for the accuracy. accuracy is improved by using a longer fft, not filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this procedure on both signals, and subtract the results to get what you want (it would be a nearly constant sequence whose value is phase shift in radians)

1. Perform FFT on the signal to obtain its spectrum.
2. Find the dominant harmonic of the signal : $f_c$ (where the peak of FFT occurs).
3. Filter the signal with a narrow-band linear phase filter (center = $f_c$, bandwidth as less as possible).
4. Again, perform FFT on the signal and extract its phase.

Note : It is assumed that the signal has a dominant frequency otherwise a phase shift is pointless

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. I could accomplish 1 and 2. Could you maybe recommend a suitable filter type for task 3? Do you think a linear phase filter should be used?

Comment: My knowledge is not enough to recommend you a suitable filter type. You can try most important ones, and choose one that works well. Yes the filter must be a linear, otherwise it will distort the phase of the inputs.

Comment: Why don't you just read the phases from the FFT bins?  What's the filter for?

Comment: @endolith the filter is arbitrary and its usage depends on the level of the noise.

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: but what does it do?  what is its purpose?  the peak bin will be the same before and after the filter

Comment: @It cancels out the noise to have a better estimate of phase

Comment: How can I compute the correct phase in step 4? If I am using angle() on the FFT outcome, the elements of the resulting vector are varying.

Comment: phase(fft(x)) does it. try to test it on 'sin(0:0.01:2*pi)'. I'm correcting a mistake in the answer.